# How to exclude sliding menu from device back button

Tags: android, android-activity, slidingmenu

I am developing an Android app that uses `slidingMenu`
I want it set up so that when a user taps on an item of sliding menu, it goes to activity 1. Then when using the menu again, it moves to activity 2.
But, when I press the back button, it shows the menu pane. I want the user to move from the second activity to the first activity; instead of showing menu. Can anyone help me please?

**Edit**
Menu has 6 items each going to a different activity and I don't know the previous activity for using intent.

Comment: This is dependent on how you are managing your Navigation Drawer (sliding menu). It seems as though you are using it as it's own activity.

Comment: yes using as own activity

Comment: You can either do what @LuisSedano said below, or you can override onPause() in your navigation drawer activity and call finish(). This will clear it from the stack any time it goes in the background.

Comment: thanks I'll test and let you know the result

Comment: My activity which menu is inside it is a base activity and stopping it cause some activities not work

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the onBackPressed() method in the second activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityOne.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);

}
```

About the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP (from http://developer.android.com):

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)** instead of activity.

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
ft.commit();
```

Also refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) documentation